# Bandwidth Reservation vs QOS

Tags: bandwidth, qos, traffic-management

what is the difference between bandwidth reservation and QOS?

for example, if I reserve 30Mbps to VOIP traffic on a router, is that the same of QOS? or does QOS work in a different way?

Comment: "Quality of Service" is a very wide term which can designate many ways of improving the quality of service. The most common way to do it, though is to establish priorities for each protocol, meaning you state that if the bandith is fully used, overlimit packets dropped will be taken from less priorized protocols.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the type of QoS you want to use. The world of QoS is vast and complex and there are many different techniques that can be combined in different ways to give a "guarantee" of service in each situation.

Actually I'd say that reserving bandwidth for VoIP is a type of QoS policy.

If you ask for a type of QoS policy in particular, you should identify it. If you ask about the type of QoS that makes a particular router, you should add the specific model to your question.

You can start reading here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service

Answer (score 1):

Put it in few words, eg. your connection is 100 Mbps.

You Reserve 10 for VOIP. All the others protocols can get at best 90 Mbps. You QoS VOIP giving it the highest priority. All other protocols are routed after VOIP. If there's no VOIP, then 100 Mbps can be used.

In telco worlds, usually QoS and reserved bandwidth are combined. By the way, 30 Mbps for VOIP? it's a total of 1500 concurrent calls with G711 codec. You are building a medium call center.

Comment: While roughly correct when interpreting "QoS" as simple priority queues (which is probably the most widely implemented algorithm marketed as "QoS"), G711 requires around 80-100 kbps per channel per direction, so 30 Mbps would be just ~300 connections.